# I have Bios Revision A24, and i noticed i am a bit few versions behind. My processor is an Intel Xeon E5-1650, and im worried that i will fry it

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard

My desktop is doing fine, but I'm worried that I will be too far behind to even update. Should i update to the latest version, or stay this way? Cant really grab another because I'm mad poor right now. My motherboard is this: 0K240Y Dell Precision T5810 Tower Workstation System Board. I'm still scared that my CPU will fry and I will have to bother my wallet.

Comment: You only need to update the bios, if you have an issue thats been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS does not control the disk - the operating system does,
so no risk of the disk dying because of the BIOS.
You do not need to update the BIOS as long as the computer boots
correctly.

Updating the BIOS is a risky operation for someone who is a novice in
these matters. I actually suggest the opposite - do not update the BIOS.
Keep your current BIOS version as long as your computer is functioning
correctly.

[if it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it.html).